# is it possible to move a composite control by clicking on one of its daughter controls?

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop

What I am attempting to accomplish is to move by drag and drop method a bunch of composite controls as outlined by the following image:

[image: CompositeControl Example]

Currently I am able to do this by only the edge of the composite control. Is it even possible to be able to click on a child/daughter control in the composite control to be able to move the entire composite control?

Here is my code for the addition of the control to `panel3` of the main form:

```
private void newPictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UserControl1 _UserControl = new UserControl1();
    PictureBox _PictureBox = (PictureBox)sender;
    string _NewControlClusterName = "_New" + _PictureBox.Name;

    _UserControl.Name = _NewControlClusterName;
    _UserControl.ThreadCount = 16;
    _UserControl.ImageBackground = _PictureBox.BackColor;
    _UserControl.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
    _UserControl.AllowDrop = true;
    _UserControl.Cursor = Cursors.SizeAll;

    _UserControl.MouseMove += _UserControl_MouseMove;
    _UserControl.DragDrop += _UserControl_DragDrop;
    _UserControl.DragEnter += _UserControl_DragEnter;

    string ColorName = toolTip1.GetToolTip(_PictureBox);
    string ColorCode = toolTip2.GetToolTip(_PictureBox);
    toolTip1.SetToolTip(_UserControl.pictureBox1, ColorName);
    toolTip2.SetToolTip(_UserControl.pictureBox1, ColorCode);
    toolTip2.Active = false;

    _UserControl.PictureClick += new EventHandler(ClusterControl_Click);
    _UserControl.TrackBarScroll += new EventHandler(GetTartanCode);

    panel3.Controls.Add(_UserControl);
    panel3.Controls.SetChildIndex(_UserControl, 0);
}

private void _UserControl_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
}

private void _UserControl_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    UserControl1 target = sender as UserControl1;
    if (target != null)
    {
        int targetIndex = FindUserControlIndex(target);
        if (targetIndex != -1)
        {
            string _UserControlFormat = typeof(UserControl1).FullName;
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(_UserControlFormat))
            {
                UserControl1 source = e.Data.GetData(_UserControlFormat) as UserControl1;
                int sourceIndex = this.FindUserControlIndex(source);
                if (targetIndex != -1)
                    this.panel3.Controls.SetChildIndex(source, targetIndex);
            }
        }
    }
}

private int FindUserControlIndex(UserControl1 _UserControl)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < this.panel3.Controls.Count; i++)
    {
        UserControl1 target = this.panel3.Controls[i] as UserControl1;
        if (_UserControl == target)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

private void _UserControl_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        UserControl1 _UserControl1 = sender as UserControl1;
        _UserControl1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
        _UserControl1.DoDragDrop(_UserControl1, DragDropEffects.All);
    }
}

private void ClusterControl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PictureBox _PictureBox = (PictureBox)sender;
    GroupBox _GroupBox = (GroupBox)_PictureBox.Parent;
    UserControl1 _UserControl1 = (UserControl1)_GroupBox.Parent;
    panel3.Controls.Remove(_UserControl1);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean during design time, or during run time?

Answer (score 2):

There is no simple way to do this.

You can try to attach your event handler to every child controls recursively.
Something like this:

```
public class UserControl1 : Control
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        // ...
        ApplyChildEvents(this);
    }

    private void ApplyChildEvents(Control control)
    {
        foreach (Control subcontrol in control.Controls)
        {
            subcontrol.MouseMove += _UserControl_MouseMove;
            subcontrol.DragDrop += _UserControl_DragDrop;
            subcontrol.DragEnter += _UserControl_DragEnter;

            ApplyChildEvents(subcontrol);
        }
    }
}
```

So, all controls on your `UserControl1` will call this method.

Comment: I understand this part, what I do not understand is, if it is possible to drag the entire control by dragging on a child control of it. For instance, the group box.

Comment: OK, made a chage to the code to reflect dynamic additions for the _USerControl by setting the properties for only the groupbox. Tried to move one of the composite controls by the groupbox and I get a NullReferenceException (Object reference not set to an instance of an object) on `_UserControl1.BorderStyle.Fixed3D;` in the _UserControl_MouseMove event handler.

Comment: @JohnSchultz Remove `sender` usage. `Sender` is of another type. Use current object's propreties.

Comment: I made an addition to the code in that event handler and will post it as an additional answer to yours. Both answers are needed to get this to work.

Comment: Followup question - any chance there is a way to animate the move. I.E. when I grab a control, the ui displays that control as being moved instead of a mouse pointer and a little box under it?

Comment: @JohnSchultz You can do this manually. For example, stop using `DoDragDrop` and `DragDrop` \ `DragEnter` events. Use `MouseDown`, `MouseUp`, `MouseMove`. I guess, that's absolutely another question :)

Answer (score 1):

Used the answer above along with the following code adjustment to the _UserControl_MouseMove event handler and it now works perfectly.

```
private void _UserControl_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        if (sender.GetType() == typeof(GroupBox))
        {
            GroupBox _GroupBox = sender as GroupBox;
            UserControl1 _UserControl1 = _GroupBox.Parent as UserControl1;
            _UserControl1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
            _UserControl1.DoDragDrop(_UserControl1, DragDropEffects.All);
        }
        else
        {
            UserControl1 _UserControl1 = sender as UserControl1;
            _UserControl1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
            _UserControl1.DoDragDrop(_UserControl1, DragDropEffects.All);
        }
    }
}
```

And also had to change the above code to the following (since the area mentioned to follow is generated on the fly):

**newPictureBox_Click**

```
foreach (Control subcontrol in _UserControl.Controls)
{
    if (subcontrol.GetType() == typeof(GroupBox)){
        subcontrol.MouseMove += _UserControl_MouseMove;
        subcontrol.DragDrop += _UserControl_DragDrop;
        subcontrol.DragEnter += _UserControl_DragEnter;
    }
}
```

Complete code is as follows:

```
private void newPictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UserControl1 _UserControl = new UserControl1();
    PictureBox _PictureBox = (PictureBox)sender;
    string _NewControlClusterName = "_New" + _PictureBox.Name;

    _UserControl.Name = _NewControlClusterName;
    _UserControl.ThreadCount = 16;
    _UserControl.ImageBackground = _PictureBox.BackColor;
    _UserControl.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
    _UserControl.AllowDrop = true;
    _UserControl.Cursor = Cursors.SizeAll;

    _UserControl.MouseMove += _UserControl_MouseMove;
    _UserControl.DragDrop += _UserControl_DragDrop;
    _UserControl.DragEnter += _UserControl_DragEnter;

    string ColorName = toolTip1.GetToolTip(_PictureBox);
    string ColorCode = toolTip2.GetToolTip(_PictureBox);
    toolTip1.SetToolTip(_UserControl.pictureBox1, ColorName);
    toolTip2.SetToolTip(_UserControl.pictureBox1, ColorCode);
    toolTip2.Active = false;

    _UserControl.PictureClick += new EventHandler(ClusterControl_Click);
    _UserControl.TrackBarScroll += new EventHandler(GetTartanCode);

    foreach (Control subcontrol in _UserControl.Controls)
    {
        if (subcontrol.GetType() == typeof(GroupBox)){
            subcontrol.MouseMove += _UserControl_MouseMove;
            subcontrol.DragDrop += _UserControl_DragDrop;
            subcontrol.DragEnter += _UserControl_DragEnter;
        }
    }

    panel3.Controls.Add(_UserControl);
    panel3.Controls.SetChildIndex(_UserControl, 0);
}

private void _UserControl_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.All;
}

private void _UserControl_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    UserControl1 target = sender as UserControl1;
    if (target != null)
    {
        int targetIndex = FindUserControlIndex(target);
        if (targetIndex != -1)
        {
            string _UserControlFormat = typeof(UserControl1).FullName;
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(_UserControlFormat))
            {
                UserControl1 source = e.Data.GetData(_UserControlFormat) as UserControl1;

                int sourceIndex = this.FindUserControlIndex(source);

                if (targetIndex != -1)
                    this.panel3.Controls.SetChildIndex(source, targetIndex);
            }
        }
    }
}

private int FindUserControlIndex(UserControl1 _UserControl)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < this.panel3.Controls.Count; i++)
    {
        UserControl1 target = this.panel3.Controls[i] as UserControl1;

        if (_UserControl == target)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

private void _UserControl_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        if (sender.GetType() == typeof(GroupBox))
        {
            GroupBox _GroupBox = sender as GroupBox;
            UserControl1 _UserControl1 = _GroupBox.Parent as UserControl1;
            _UserControl1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
            _UserControl1.DoDragDrop(_UserControl1, DragDropEffects.All);
        }
        else
        {
            UserControl1 _UserControl1 = sender as UserControl1;
            _UserControl1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
            _UserControl1.DoDragDrop(_UserControl1, DragDropEffects.All);
        }
    }
}
```