# Possible to animate a drag and drop function for a winforms ui app?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, drag-and-drop

This question is a follow up question to post:

> [Is it possible to move a composite control by clicking on one of its
>   daughter controls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33513651/is-it-possible-to-move-a-composite-control-by-clicking-on-one-of-its-daughter-co)

Is it possible to animate the actual drag and drop movement. I.E. instead of having just a mouse pointer and a small rectangular box underneath, display something that looks like the composite control?

Answer (score 0):

The first approach is to simply create an static icon that looks like the composite control and for example embed it in an application as a resource. Then you have to use it as a custom drag and drop icon. This answer [Can I choose a custom image for C# Windows Application Drag Drop functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078211/can-i-choose-a-custom-image-for-c-sharp-windows-application-drag-drop-functions) explains how to do that.

The second approach is more complex. Instead of using a static icon you can create an icon dynamically based on the current content of a control being dragged. The following answer [C# Drag-and-Drop: Show the dragged item while dragging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240603/c-sharp-drag-and-drop-show-the-dragged-item-while-dragging) explains it in more details.

Comment: I would do the second option, however, there is code missing to get it to work :(.